# Call to action on the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, actioncontroller

I am learning rails and I have a question
  How can I call an action from another in the same controller?

```
def new
  new_method()
end

private

def new_method
 ...
end
```

This would be the right way?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Btw. you do not need the empty parenthesis.

Comment: I understand, very thank's for you reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis is optional in Ruby. But, one `action` receive a call from client and respond one output. Your private "action" is only a `function` or `method`.

```
class User
    def create
      make_something(params)
    end

    private
    def make_something(params)
      #some implementation
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much
I can already understand the difference between action and function or method
Thanks for your reply